# I can't read an excel file into pandas on python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, database, dataframe

The file is in a folder on my desktop

See my code below

pd.read_excel('C:/Users/ANGEL/Desktop/Akin Kyosk doc/Sales.xlsx')

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqp6E.png)

I have attached my code and it's still not working

I need suggestion or explanation on what could be the cause

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you a file not found error, indicating that something is incorrect with your file path.

Try creating the file path with (replacing with correct folder names)

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(each, individual, directory, file_name)
print(os.path.exists(filepath))
```

Then import with pandas once your filepath is correct

FWIW, it is often easier to copy the error code into a code block instead of uploading an image.

Comment: I understand what you meant by (each, individual, directory, file_name)

How does it apply to this 'C:/Users/ANGEL/Desktop/Akin Kyosk doc/Sales.xlsx'

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem a long time ago, it was caused by specials chars in path, first time it was caused cuz I had "{" in path and second time it was caused by space in file path, so try to rename your folder from Akin Kyosk Doc to Akin_Kyosk_Doc or use path like "./Sales.xlsx"

Comment: Thanks, I have just done that but the error code remains

"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/ANGEL/Desktop/Akin_Kyosk_doc/Sales.xlsx'"

Comment: Hello All,

I still need guidance on my question.

Anybody can assist please

Comment: Please I still need assistance on how to resolve my question above

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is in this directory.
open up a console and try

```
dir C:/Users/ANGEL/Desktop/Akin_Kyosk_doc
```